# How to return a result from terminal in web server

Tags: php, windows

I need to find a way to return a result from a program writed in C++ (or fortran) that gives information on a terminal in a web server.

Currently, I'm using PHP, tried to use exec, shell_exec and system and didn't work.

Actually, it worked when I called the file with CMD (windows) using php.exe exec("path\to\file\.exe"). But not when I tried with localhost in a browser, maybe because of permission problems:

```
<?php
    $out = exec("C:\wamp64\www\Teste\main.exe");
    print_r($out);
?>
```

I've already changed permissions on the file and the entire folder.

How to do this?

***EDIT***

Basically, I went for services.msc, finded wampapache64 and changed local account to mine. Now I can run this file from browser.

But the question is maintained: Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exec("path/to/foo.exe", $output);
print_r($output);
```

Note that the output variable will be an array with your output lines.
Of course the server should be a server that knows how to run exe files

Of course it is important to note, the code will not run on the browser of the target computer but on the server where it has the PHP code

Comment: Thanks. So the problem was lack of permission. I solved with services.msc.

Comment: If my answer helps you, please mark this question as resolved. Thnaks